# VTK: Compiling with Java Wrappers - vtk.jar missing

Tags: java, visual-studio, cmake, vtk

I am trying to build VTK under Windows 10 for use in Java using Visual Studio 2019 basically according to this [this](http://conrad.stanford.edu/tutorials/itk-and-vtk-wrapping/wrap-vtk/index.html) and [this](https://www.particleincell.com/2011/vtk-java-visualization/) tutorial. The `cmake` part seems to work fine. I end up with the following config:

[image]

The build step (Build `ALL_BUILD`) in Visual Studio with `Release` solution configuration for `x64` as admin seemingly also does work:

```
========== Build: 437 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, executing `INSTALL` ends with an error:

```
225>CMake Error at Wrapping/Java/cmake_install.cmake:1215 (file):
225>  file INSTALL cannot find
225>  "[PATH]/VTK-9.0.1/Binaries/lib/java/Release/vtk.jar":
225>  File exists.
225>Call Stack (most recent call first):
225>  cmake_install.cmake:486 (include)
225>
225>
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: D:\Programme\CMake\3.20.3\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
225>D:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
225>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

and indeed, there are lots of `*.exp` and `*.lib` files in `[PATH]/VTK-9.0.1/Binaries/lib/java/Release/` but a `vtk.jar` is missing.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, better should have searched 3 minutes longer. But for sake of completeness, here is the solution:

https://discourse.vtk.org/t/vtk-9-and-java-vtk-jar-not-automatically-generated-also-location-of-wrapper-dlls/3354/19

The essence:

> The VS cmake does not know how to build java files so the last stage
> of building the jar file has to be done manually since vtk 9.0.0

The relevant code from the link

```
cd $vtk_build_dir\Wrapping\Java
dir /s/B *.java >javafiles
javac -d ..\..\java @javafiles
cd ..\..\java
jar --create -f  ..\lib\java\vtk.jar vtk\*.class
```